# Why is the vertical scrollbar not working in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, grid

I am currently doing the FreeCodeCamp course and I am trying to replicate this website: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/NdrKKL. The navigation bar on the left has a vertical scrollbar. On other posts I read that setting the parents' height element to 100% would fix it. Somehow, I can't seem to fix this in my code. This is the current state of my website: https://codepen.io/otapadar/full/VwKBvXB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. See below my code:

PS: I have added borders around each list-element. They overlap, which makes the border twice as thick as I intend them to be. If someone also knows how to fix this, then that would also be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time!

HTML (Only important stuff):

```
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<nav id="navbar">
  <header>
    <h1>JS Documentation</h1>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#introduction>Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#what_you_should_know>What You Should Know</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#javascript_and_java>JavaScript and Java</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#hello_world>Hello World</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#variables>Variables</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#declaring_variables>Declaring Variables</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#variable_scope>Variable Scope</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#global_variables>Global Variables</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#constants>Constants</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#data_types>Data Types</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#if/else_statements>If/Else Statements</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#while_statements>While Statements</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS (Everything):

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 100%;
}

code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  min-width: 290px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

nav > header {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav > ul > li {
  border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

main {
  margin-left: 310px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: `height: 100%` will use the full contents height. You need to sue a definite height as viewheight to give the navbar as definite height and allowing it to overflow with a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `ul` height to: `calc(100vh - 4em);`. The Header of the navbar has a height of `2em` (h1) and a padding top and bottom of `1em` each equals `4em`. That way the list has a definite height and can actually use a scrollbar to overflow. With height: 100% it will takes 100% of the contents height as height and therefor it will be impossible to actually overflow.

```css
* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

code {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  min-width: 290px;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav > header {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 4em);
}

nav > ul > li {
  border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

main {
  margin-left: 310px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>

<nav id="navbar">
  <header>
    <h1>JS Documentation</h1>
  </header>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#introduction>Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#what_you_should_know>What You Should Know</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#javascript_and_java>JavaScript and Java</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#hello_world>Hello World</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#variables>Variables</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#declaring_variables>Declaring Variables</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#variable_scope>Variable Scope</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#global_variables>Global Variables</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#constants>Constants</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#data_types>Data Types</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#if/else_statements>If/Else Statements</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link" href=#while_statements>While Statements</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! Appreciate it. May I ask why you changed the box-sizing property to border-box? I don't see any difference in the output. Once again, thanks! You really helped me out.

Comment: @user1371018 IT is just good habit. That way, it will be ensured that the calculation with the call function works correctly. In case a margin of the child's or a padding of the harbor is added, it would make the call function incorrect. With border-box, a margin of passng could be added without influencing the calcluation

Answer (score 0):

make the height to 100% and for li remove border-bottom. Please check the following code.

```
nav {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #a9a9a9;
  min-width: 290px;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
nav > ul > li{
    border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
```

Comment: have you checked the code line on your own? will not work as intended. If you would use a runnable code snippet, you could see it for yoruself. The issue is, that `height: 100%` will adjust the height according to the contents height and therefor cant technically overflow. You need to use a definite height value.